# Using aspectj to intercept an assignment with reflection

Tags: java, reflection, aop, aspectj

When I run the application with tomcat it says that the advices has not been aplied, so my aspects won't work. Do I have to configure that anywhere? I haven't done anything about it, so I don't know what code might be useful.

Thank you!

**EDIT**

I've just found out how to fix that, and even when it says that the aspect has not been applied, when I call the setter it works, but I have a problem when using reflection for that.

I have an aspect which intercept a setter to a field which works well, but when the value is assigned from Gson library por example, it doesn't work.

This is the aspect:

```
public aspect AnnotationAspect {

    pointcut hasAnnotation(Annotation annotation) : @annotation(annotation);

    Object around(Annotation annotation, String word) : hasAnnotation(annotation) && set(String *) && args(word) {
        Object result = null;
        try {
            result = proceed(annotation, "intercepted");
        } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
            throw ex;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

And I have this class:

```
public class JavaEntity {

    @Annotation
    public String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

When I do something like this it does not intercept the assignment:

```
JavaEntity entity = new Gson().fromJson("{\"name\":\"name\"}", JavaEntity.class);
```

Is there anyway to intercept that? Thank you!

Comment: Details, please. Do you use compile-time or load-time weaving? When "it says" something, why don't you just post the relevant part of the server log? There are no code, no config, no log. How can you expect anyone to be able to answer your question like this? I explained that to you before. Please learn [how to ask a question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You know, as I also told others before, I am not a medium and cannot read thoughts - a mentalist maybe, but in this case that is not enough. ;-)

Comment: Sorry for that, I've just edited the question and the problem has changed now. I posted that because of the messages that the IDE shows, but when debugging I found out that the common setter works well, the problem is with reflection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reflective field access cannot be directly intercepted by AspectJ. You could only work around it by fighting fire with fire, i.e. also using reflection:

- Make sure Gson is on the *inpath* for the AspectJ compiler (i.e. a weave dependency for AspectJ Maven plugin) so as to be able to weave into its code.
- Intercept calls to `Field.set(..)`.
- In the intercepting advice check which field is to be set, look up its annotations via reflection in order to emulate `@annotation(blah)`, decide whether to modify its value or not.

This is not exactly the usual AspectJ use case, but possible.

BTW, you do not have this kind of problem with `execution()` joinpoints because they are also triggered when a method is called reflectively. You would have the problem with `call()`, though. But this is just for your information, not directly related to this specific case.

---

**Update:** I mean something like this:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <weaveDependencies>
            <weaveDependency>
                <groupId>Group</groupId>
                <artifactId>model</artifactId>
            </weaveDependency>
            <weaveDependency>
                <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
                <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            </weaveDependency>
        </weaveDependencies>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

```java
@Test
public void testingInterceptWithJavaGson(){
    javaEntity = new Gson().fromJson("{\"name\":\"newName\"}", JavaEntity.class);
    Assert.assertEquals("intercepted", javaEntity.getName());
}
```

```java
Object around(Field field, Object obj, Object value) :
    within(com.google.gson..*) &&
    call(public void Field.set(Object, Object)) &&
    target(field) &&
    args(obj, value)
{
    Object result = null;
    System.out.println(thisJoinPoint);
    System.out.println("  " + field + " -> " + field.getAnnotation(Annotation.class));
    System.out.println("  " + obj);
    System.out.println("  " + value);
    try {
        if (field.getAnnotation(Annotation.class) != null && field.getType() == String.class)
            result = proceed(field, obj, "intercepted");
        else
            result = proceed(field, obj, value);
    } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
        throw ex;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Actually you do not need to bind the first parameter `obj` via `args()`, I just use it for logging so as to show you what happens there. So this slightly simpler form will also do:

```java
Object around(Field field, Object value) :
    within(com.google.gson..*) &&
    call(public void Field.set(Object, Object)) &&
    target(field) &&
    args(*, value)
{
    Object result = null;
    System.out.println(thisJoinPoint);
    try {
        if (field.getAnnotation(Annotation.class) != null && field.getType() == String.class)
            result = proceed(field, "intercepted");
        else
            result = proceed(field, value);
    } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
        throw ex;
    }
    return result;
}
```

The changes to your existing [GitHub repo](https://github.com/tsandler/aspectj-with-scala) are contained in yet another [pull request](https://github.com/tsandler/aspectj-with-scala/pull/3) from my fork.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and explanation. Sorry for this question, but what you mean with "Make sure Gson is on the inpath for the AspectJ compiler"? How can I do/check that?

Comment: The sentence has a second part in parentheses which explains it. ;-)

Comment: Yes, but I did't understand it at all. Where do I have to weave the dependency?

Comment: See update. I am quite busy creating pull requests for you today. Lucky you that I have some spare time this weekend. ;-)